# Anonymous graphs and graph embeddedness

Tags: graph-theory, definition

What are anonymous graphs, what is graph embeddedness, and how do they relate to each other? Very confused - I could not find short answer. Thanks.

Comment: possibly relevant: http://people.scs.carleton.ca/~santoro/Reports/DaFKNS07.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Anonymous graphs are graphs that do not contain any labels and vertices cannot be identified.
According to [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clustering_coefficient), embeddedness describes how close the neighbors of a vertex are to being a clique and this can be measured by calculating the local clustering coefficient.